# Where is the SQL File Template in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010

I notice in VS2010's Tools > Options dialog, there is a section on how to format the SQL:

[image: PL/SQL Options]

I am working with a very large stored procedure on our server that is not formatted well at all. I was thinking it would be great to create a new SQL File in my project, copy and paste the text from the stored procedure in there, and have the text editor apply auto formatting to all of the SQL.

When I call "Add > New Item" and get that dialog, there does not seem to be any Installed Template with the .sql extension.

[image: Add New Item Dialog]

I see the **SQL Server Database** template, but that is not what I need. The **LINQ to SQL Classes** is not right, either.

What template do I need to use to use the auto formatting built into the VS2010 interface?

Comment: There is also a **Transact-SQL** settings section in the Options, but it would need to be scrolled down past the **Text Editor** section to be visible.

Comment: I have found these links, but none show what type of Template it is working with: [Transact-SQL IntelliSense](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee362019(v=vs.100).aspx), [Transact-SQL IntelliSense Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee362021(v=vs.100).aspx), [Using Transact-SQL Code Snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee362022(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Judging from your screenshot, you have a C# project (e.g. a library dll) open. This won't show an option to add a .sql file as those files are not normally associated with a C# kind of projects.

One way around it is:

1. In VS2010 main menu, go to File -> New -> File. In General tab, there's a SqlFile file type. [image]
2. Add a file and save it to the disk in the location of your project.
3. Right-click on your project and select Add -> Existing Item. In the open file dialog, change the extension to `*.*` to show your .sql file.
4. Add file to the project. If needed, change "Build Action" and "Copy to Output Directory" properties to control how it behaves during the build.

Comment: Also a good option - I hadn't thought of working around it like this. Whenever I add SQL to my projects I usually contain them in a project just to separate them, but occasionally it is annoying. +1

Comment: That is **EXACTLY** what I wanted to do. SO says I can award you this bounty in 4 hours.

Comment: YAAAA! 100 bucks! Go buy a round of drinks! :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for shows up when you create a SQL Server Database project.

> File > Add > New Project

[image: Add SQL Project]

Then when you add items you see options that should work:

[image: Options]

*Note my screenshots are from VS2012 - but I think it is the same.

Comment: +1. This is probably the most correct answer, but Szymon showed how to do exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I hate Visual Studio's T-SQL designer, even with SQL Data Tools installed. I opt to open my project's .sql files in Management Studio.

Right-Click any .sql file in VS. 
Navigate to "Open-with"
Choose "Add"

In the Program dialog type "explorer.exe"
Type whatever you want for the friendly Name, I use Management Studio

Click "OK"

Highlight the new record and choose "Set as default".

Now double clicking any .sql file in VS will open up whatever program opens when you double click a .sql file outside of VS. Using this method, I'm able to edit, add, and modify my sql files in management studio and save them back to the project seamlessly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good idea (+1), but Szymon's answer is what I was trying to figure out how to do.